# Regular Expression needed - dollars with no cents

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that matches numbers after a dollar sign but have no cents afterwards.

> $33.92 - no match
>
> $211 - match 211

This is what I have so far.

```
(?<=\$)\d+(?!\.)
```

Looking at this string...

> Something $122.30 $45 $1.111

... it is CORRECTLY matching "45", but it is also matching "12".

I understand why it is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: This is actually for adding GREP styles to InDesign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=\$)\d+(?![.\d])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mTiN1z/1).

Synonymic expressions showing the use of possessive quantifier and atomic grouping:

```
(?<=\$)\d++(?!\.)
(?<=\$)(?>\d+)(?!\.)
```

An expression for those environments where lookbehind is not supported should have a capturing group around the `\d+` pattern:

```
\$(\d+)(?![.\d])
  ^   ^
```

Then the value needed is in Group 1.

And just FYI: `\$([0-9]+)($|[^.0-9])` will work even with POSIX ERE.

**Details**

- `(?<=\$)` - a `$` must apppear immediately to the left of the current position
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?![.\d])` - no dot or digit should appear immediately to the right of the current position.

Regex graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `PCRE` engines ( `PHP`, etc.) you could use

```
\$\d+\.\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\$\d+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/LbrvZc/1/).

---

Broken down this reads:

```
\$\d+\.\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # match any $123.3323223 format
                         # and "forget" the matches
|                        # or
\$\d+                    # match your desired format
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use that work with me 
(?<=\$)\d++(?!.)